Can not login in Keycloak after import database
I develop and deploy the Keycloak system on my Staging server. Everything works well, so I deploy it to the UAT server. The Staging server and the UAT server use the same Docker image. I export the PostgreSQL database from the Staging server and import it to the UAT server. When I tried logging in to the admin account on the UAT server, I got the error 'Username or password incorrect' even though this admin account logs in normally on the Staging server. How do I fix this error?
